# Codeacademy: Move to next lesson with keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I know that when you want to enter your code, you can press command(or windows) + Enter. But after that, you have to click the arrow at the bottom of the screen to go forward. Does anyone know if there's a keyboard shortcut to get past this? I can't figure it out.

The reason I ask is I'm using an external keyboard, since the keys on my laptop are getting sticky. So I'm a good distance away from the track pad when I'm working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't found also this.
But i check a few card with lession and all the forward button have same id = id="discovery-next".

I think there is way to make a macro for using this ;P